# FLUTTER how to assign a var of type color to a final

Tags: flutter

This does not work because 
"a value of type color can not be assigned to a variable of type colors"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final Colors HOMEPAGE_BUTTON_COLOR = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
```

If I want to assign a color to a final var, how should this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Color` instead of `Colors`.

```
final Color HOMEPAGE_BUTTON_COLOR = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
```

Answer (score 0):

> //Declare color variable in your page like this
>
> Color SuperColor = Colors.red;
>
> //initialise the color in intState();
>
> if(globals.userRole=="Super Admin") {
> SuperColor = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5);
> } else{
> SuperColor = Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5); }
>
> //and call them whenever you required
>
> > Blockquote
>
> color: this.SuperColor,